# Unexplainable Singleton / Picocli behaviour

Tags: java, singleton, picocli

I'm writing some code and I can't figure out what's going on with the bug I have. I hope someone here can give me some answers. Here is my code (the relevant part):

```
public class AppData implements Callable<Integer> {
    private static AppData appData = new AppData();

    private AppData() {
        System.out.println("AppData-Constructor");
    }

    public static AppData getInstance() {
        return appData;
    }

    @Override
    public Integer call() throws Exception { // your business logic goes here...
        return 0;
    }

    private boolean _validate;

    public boolean validate() {
        return _validate;
    }

    @Option(names = { "--validate" }, description = "", defaultValue = "false", hidden = false, interactive = false, paramLabel = "", required = false, type = boolean.class)
    public void set_validate(boolean validate) {
        System.out.println("Set Validate: " + validate);
        this._validate = validate;

        if(validate)
        {
            System.out.println("\nBeginne Programmvalidierung\n");
            Path tmp = null;
            try {
                // Doing some validation stuff
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

}
```

As you can see my class is a singleton. The annotation is from picoli, which I use to parse the command line arguments. The `System.out`-calls are for debugging. This is the behaviour I can't explain:

When I start my app with e.g. "-h" as argument, I get the help printed just fine. The `System.out.println`show that the singleton is created and that `set_validate()` is called with the default value. But that changes when I use `--validate` as an argument.

For some reason, the constructor and default set are called twice in a row. After that, `set_validate()`
 is called with `true` (as it should). However, it seems that the first call sets the static instance variable, while the last call with true is done on the second instance (my theory). As a consequence, when I check the state of `_validate` with `validate()` on my singleton instance from my main method (in another class) I get false, as it wasn't set in the right instance.

I used a search engine to check:

1. The constructor is not called anywhere except for the static singleton instance (as expected, since it's private).
2. `_validate` is not accessed anywhere except the code I posted.
3. `set_validate()` is not called anywhere. Only Picocli calls it.

I don't know what to check next. Any ideas?

Regards

Thorsten

EDIT:
`AppData` is one of multiple classes holding the data. They are all collected in one big class for Picocli like this:

```
class Data
{
    @AddGroup(...)
    AppData appData = AppData.getInstance();

    @AddGroup(...)
    FooData fooData = FooData.getInstance();

    @AddGroup(...)
    BarData barData = BarData.getInstance();
}
```

It's used like this in my main method:

```
Data data = new Data();
CommandLine cmd = new CommandLine(data);
cmd.parseArgs(args);
```

Comment: if you have your constructor generate a stacktrace and write it to the console, then you should be able to see what is calling it whenever the constructor is called. maybe that would give you a hint.

Comment: I'm not familiar with Picoli but it seems it must construct its own instance of the annotated class, even though it has a private constructor. I wonder what would happen if you implmented the singleton pattern using an enum instead of a class with a static field.

Comment: @NathanHughes I tried that. As far as I can tell it shows that the second instacne is created using reflection, like the answer by Remko says.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect (but can only guess, since that part of the code is not shown) that `AppData` is either a subcommand of another command, or that the application uses picocli like this:

```
int exitCode = new CommandLine(AppData.class).execute(args);
```

In both cases, picocli will create an instance of `AppData` using reflection. The instance created by picocli is the instance populated from the command line values. This is a different instance than the one returned by `AppData::getInstance`.

One way to ensure there is only one instance is to pass *the singleton instance* to picocli. For example:

```
AppData singleton = AppData.getInstance();
int exitCode = new CommandLine(singleton).execute(args);

System.out.println("validate=" + singleton.validate());
```

(If `AppData` is a subcommand there are other ways to access the instance that picocli created, like the [`@Spec` annotation](https://picocli.info/#spec-annotation) to inject the picocli model, and calling `CommandSpec::userObject()` getter on that to get the `AppData` instance.)

Now, the other question is: why does the `set_validate` method get invoked twice?

As of version 4.2, picocli will first call `@Option`-annotated methods with the default value, before parsing the command line parameters. So the `set_validate` method is first invoked with the default value, and then called again with the value specified on the command line.

(From version 4.3 (to be released soon), the default value will [only be set if the value is not specified](https://github.com/remkop/picocli/issues/961) on the command line, so from version 4.3 the `set_validate` method will only be invoked once.)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I lokked at the stacktrace as suggested and that shows reflection being used. But I actually pass an object to Picocli. I will edit my question to add this information.

Comment: Thank you. The stacktrace may also be useful. A small runnable program that reproduces the problem would be ideal.